# SonarQube | New Code Period & Code Coverage

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage

Greetings !!!

I am using SonarQube: Version 7.4 & have added below plugins SonarQube new QualityGate:

1. LineCoverage on new code
2. Condition Coverage on new code
3. Coverage on new code
4. New Code Period

To implement: *New Code Period (Number of days)*

**My requirement**: To add a new code period SonarQube plugin for the existing project (project-1)

What I did:

1. I create a new Sonar Quality Gate for a project
2. Removed existing Sonar report for the project-1
3. Added “New Code Period - Number of days (2020-10-20)” plugin from SonarQube specific to project-1

**Problem statement:**

**1st**: After executing SonarQube CI, I am not able to see any new issue appear (wrt New Code Period) in the dashboard (since the day I mentioned - 2020-10-20)

*Is it due to Sonar Project is newly created (without any history) which would fail to fetch the issue from the past days?*

**2nd**: If I rerun the SonarQube CI without any code update in Project-1, Line Coverage on new code/Condition Coverage on new code appear as ***0%***

*Is this due to No NEW code added from the last build?*

I would like to know what could be the issue. Any help, pointers, suggestions would be grateful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

For 0% Coverage, below is the fix with the below updates

In all Coverage, I have UnChecked the ‘On New Code’ and only use ‘Coverage on New Code’ to track the new code quality. It worked as expected.

Snapshot:
Prior 0% Coverage
[image]

**Update (After uncheck new Code):**

[image]

And also New Code Period changes are reflecting.
[image]

Thanks, everyone :)